# ***** instead of truncating a field in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I was wondering if there was a way in Crystal to do the following:

If a field has a character limit of 10 characters...and the data fed in has 11 characters, instead of showing truncated data, i'd like it to show **** .  Excel has a function like this where if a column is too narrow for a field to show completely, it shows ###### instead of the data.

Is there a way to do this for numeric fields and string fields?

I have tried:

```
if length {DataTable1.Name} < 4 then {DataTable1.Name} else '****'
```

also,

```
if length {DataTable1.Name} > 4 then '*****'
```

Neither works.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Crystal Syntax, this works for me:

```
If Length({DataTable1.Name}) < 4 Then {DataTable1.Name} Else '****'
```

Edit:
Since you can possibly have numbers, you'll want something more like this:

```
If Length(ToText({Command.ORD_NUM_VALUE})) < 4.00 
    Then ToText({Command.ORD_NUM_VALUE}) Else '****'
```

I get a little wary of casting like this though.  Hopefully you can find a better solution for your problem.

Comment: this does work for strings...but a lot of my fields are numerical values.  will it still work for that?